# Changing ncurses 6 "terminfo-dirs" after compilation/installation

Tags: ncurses, terminfo

There is a ncurses6 originally installed in a user home dir, let's say "/home/test", so a test environment was built over this ncurses path, a lot of (in development) apps were compiled and is working now, depending only of the current HOME env variable.

But, because of a purpose beyond our control, we have to change the user home dir. And now it's anything different from "/home/test".

The external apps and ncurses tools still working, we need just point the libraries with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and use a more specific path like we used before for ncurses tools:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/bin/ncurses-6.0/lib ~/bin/ncurses-6.0/bin/tic
```

But now, after changing the user home dir, we need to point also the terminfo database:

```
TERMINFO=~/bin/ncurses-6.0/share/terminfo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/bin/ncurses-6.0/lib ~/bin/ncurses-6.0/bin/tic
```

But, is there any way to make the TERMINFO database path permanent without recompiling and reinstalling the ncurses ? Is it hard code in ncurses during compilation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default values are compiled-in.  You can override those with environment variables ([**`TERMINFO`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) is standard, [**`TERMINFO_DIRS`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS) is an extension).  That's not new with ncurses6 (it predates ncurses4, twenty years ago).

The most practical "permanent" change would be to put the overrides in your shell initialization.

It's possible to modify an ELF binary (there's no checksums), but the resulting path couldn't be longer.  It *could* be shorter, since the strings are null-terminated.  Since your example adds to the path, that wouldn't work for you, anyway.